# Compilers targeting .pyc files?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, pyc

Out of curiosity, are there many compilers out there which target `.pyc` files?

After a bit of Googling, the only two I can find are:

- [unholy](http://github.com/whymirror/unholy): why_'s Ruby-to-pyc compiler
- [Python](http://python.org/): The PSF's Python to pyc compiler

So… Are there any more?

(as a side note, I got thinking about this because I want to write a Scheme-to-pyc compiler)

(as a second side note, I'm not under any illusion that a Scheme-to-pyc compiler would be *useful*, but it would give me an incredible excuse to learn some internals of both Scheme and Python)

Comment: I'm fairly sure `unholy` only exists because _why is crazy.  (Crazy awesome to be precise.)

Comment: If you want to generate code that executes in the Python runtime, by far the better approach is to generate Python code and compile it, not try to generate Python bytecode directly.

Comment: @Glenn agreed – a Scheme-to-Python compiler would be much more sensible… But I don't want to be sensible here, I want to learn about Python's internals (and what it takes to implement Scheme)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a compiler several years ago which accepted a lisp-like language called "Noodle" and produced Python bytecode. While it never became particularly useful, it was a tremendously good learning experience both for understanding Common Lisp better (I copied several of its features) and for understanding Python better.

I can think of two particular cases when it might be useful to target Python bytecode directly, instead of producing Python and passing it on to a Python compiler:

1. Full closures: in Python before 3.0 (before the `nonlocal` keyword), you can't modify the value of a closed-over variable without resorting to bytecode hackery. You can mutate values instead, so it's common practice to have a closure referencing a list, for example, and changing the first element in it from the inner scope. That can get real annoying. The restriction is part of the syntax, though, not the Python VM. My language had explicit variable declaration, so it successfully provided "normal" closures with modifiable closed-over values.
2. Getting at a traceback object without referencing any builtins. Real niche case, for sure, but I used it to break an early version of the "safelite" jail. See [my posting](http://thepaulprog.blogspot.com/2009/02/safelite-exploit.html) about it.

So yeah, it's probably way more work than it's worth, but I enjoyed it, and you might too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Paul! I'm glad to know that I'm not insane :) Also, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

"I want to write a Scheme-to-pyc compiler".

My brain hurts!  Why would you want to do that?  Python byte code is an intermediate language specifically designed to meet the needs of the Python language and designed to run on Python virtual machines that, again, have been tailored to the needs of Python.  Some of the most important areas of Python development these days are moving Python to other "virtual machines", such as [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) (JVM), [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython) (.NET), [PyPy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/) and the [Unladen Swallow](http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/) project (moving CPython to an [LLVM](http://llvm.org/)-based representation). Trying to squeeze the syntax and semantics of another, very different language (Scheme) into the intermediate representation of another high-level language seems to be attacking the problem (whatever the problem is) at the wrong level. So, in general, it doesn't seem like there would be many .pyc compilers out there and there's a good reason for that.

Comment: Why would I want to do that? What's *not* to like about it?! I get to learn about the internals of both Scheme AND Python (albeit at different levels… But still)!

Comment: But, more seriously, you've got a good point that I didn't consider: pyc, unlike general bytecode (.swf or .class?), is designed only to suit Python… So it doesn't make much sense to target it.

Comment: At least, it doesn't make sense if your goal is to produce something useful :P

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you focus on CPython.

http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/CompiledPythonfiles.html

Rather than a Scheme to .pyc translator, I suggest you write a Scheme to Python translator, and then let CPython handle the conversion to .pyc.  (There is precedent for doing it this way; the first C++ compiler was [Cfront](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront) which translated C++ into C, and then let the system C compiler do the rest.)

From what I know of Scheme, it wouldn't be that difficult to translate Scheme to Python.

One warning: the Python virtual machine is probably not as fast for Scheme as Scheme itself.  For example, Python doesn't automatically turn tail recursion into iteration; and Python has a relatively shallow stack, so you would actually need to turn tail recursion to iteration for your translator.

As a bonus, once Unladen Swallow speeds up Python, your Scheme-to-Python translator would benefit, and at that point might even become practical!

If this seems like a fun project to you, I say go for it.  Not every project has to be immediately practical.

P.S. If you want a project that is somewhat more practical, you might want to write an AWK to Python translator.  That way, people with legacy AWK scripts could easily make the leap forward to Python!

Comment: Um, he already has CPython in his list: that's the PSF's Python to pyc compiler.

Comment: Hhhmm… Awk to Python… That's even more disgusting… But *does* have the drawback of being potentially useful…

Comment: The main reason I suggested it is, I answered a question about making a standalone binary from an AWK file.  Python has several ways to make a standalone binary (e.g. for Windows, Py2Exe: http://www.py2exe.org/).  If you could translate AWK to Python you could then make a standalone binary!

Comment: @Ned Deily: you are only saying that because it's true... fine, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just for your interest, I have written a toy compiler from a simple LISP to Python. Practically, this is a LISP to pyc compiler.

Have a look: [sinC - The tiniest LISP compiler](http://bernhardkausler.wordpress.com/2009/11/28/sinc-%E2%80%94-the-tiniest-lisp-compiler-to-python/)

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late at the party but if you're still interested the clojure-py project (https://github.com/halgari/clojure-py) is now able to compile a significant subset of clojure to python bytecode -- but some help is always welcome.

Targeting bytecode is not that hard in itself, except for one thing: it is not stable across platforms (e.g. MAKE_FUNCTION pops 2 elements from the stack in Python 3 but only 1 in Python 2), and these differences are not clearly documented in a single spot (afaict) -- so you probably have some abstraction layer needed.